# Html form - php - mysql date field?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date

Assume that I'm adding the date / time into a mysql database and have the following (small for once) chunk of code.

```
<input type="text" name="date">Leave time null for current<br />
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

The Following is the form that catches that

```
$radate=$_POST['date'];
if ($radate=="")
$radate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
else {}
```

I've tried entering "2011-08-14 19:15:25" and it has returned all 0's, can someone help me out with this?  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably be better off using [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to validate the date/time submitted, if it's a freeform date entry field especially. Otherwise, someone may miss-enter a date/time and unexpectedly have it use the current date/time instead.

```
$radate_valid = false;
$radate = $_POST['date'];
if (!$radate)
    $radate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if (strtotime($radate) === false)
    $radate_valid = false;
else
    $radate_valid = true;

// Somewhere else
if ($radate_valid !== true) 
    /* Do something to warn the user. */
```

http://codepad.org/x2eZay0Q

If you used dropdowns, and the time was not a factor, you could also use [`checkdate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php), although from your example it looks like you do need the time.

However, what you have posted should work. Here is an example using your date you provided:

http://codepad.org/BK1yqyMT

(And here without fixing the `if` block: http://codepad.org/p3CfmOJK)

Comment: Awesome, I didn't even know that this existed!

Comment: I've been doing PHP for seven years now, and I still come across functions/capabilities that I wasn't aware of that have existed for a long time.

Comment: Note, I just realized something... You need to test for validation in addition to the date check when it is provided. Sorry about that. See my last edit.